# It's April 2019, what's a good tutorial on how to link a web dapp to scatter or some other mobile wallet?

Tags: scatter, mobile, meet.one-wallet, lynx-wallet, tutorial

There have been a few tutorials on how to link scatter to a dapp which is just html/js, but those could be outdated due to the speed that eos has developed. What is the latest tutorial on how to link scatter or a mobile wallet to a dapp as of **April 2019**? What I'm interested in is how does one use their html/js application to communicate with the scatter desktop wallet and mobile wallets like Lynx/Meet.one --- How does clicking on the "login" button on the static html/js page make these wallets popup to prompt you to authorize a login?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best tutorial is to take a look at the ***Universal Authenticator Library - UAL*** and how it works.

Here are some helpful links:

- [Medium Article about the UAL](https://medium.com/eosio/eosio-labs-release-the-universal-authenticator-library-ual-increasing-the-accessibility-of-8e2bd62a78a5)
- [UAL Authenticator Walkthrough](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-authenticator-walkthrough)
- [UAL Github-Repository](https://github.com/EOSIO/universal-authenticator-library)

There are are several different UAL-Repositories + Usage-Examples for use with the different available Wallets.

- [Scattter UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-scatter)
- [Lynx UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-lynx)
- [Ledger UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-ledger)
- [Token-Pocket UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-token-pocket)
- [Meet.One UAL](https://github.com/meet-one/ual-meetone)

Comment: None of these help. Any other examples?

Answer (score 0):

Scatter's documentation is pretty good, it has some decent examples and is what I used along with eosjs.

https://get-scatter.com/docs/getting-started

https://github.com/GetScatter/scatter-js

I assume you've already looked at those, but they're definitely the best starting points :)